# authentication of the google disk api on the hosting

Tags: google-api, hosting

I have a telegram bot, there is a function for sending files to Google drive. While I was testing locally, it worked well, after I uploaded to a remote hosting, everything broke
[error in logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MABRk.png)

the authorization code looks like this:

```
def getCreds():
    creds = None
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
    secrets_file = 'client_secrets.json'
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            # I ran this code for local use
            # flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            #     'client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
            # creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
            # creds, _ = flow.authorization_url()
            # flow.fetch_token(code='')
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(secrets_file)

        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    return creds
```

what should the code look like in order for it to work correctly on a remote server?